# Composite View Pattern: communicate error messages from subviews to main view

Tags: design-patterns, mvvm

I have some problems on how to communicate error messages form subviews to the main view.

My application uses a Composite view pattern for the UI. This means that each page has subpages. Each page uses the MVVM pattern

Heres an Example structure of a window:

```
AddRecipePage
    BasisInformationPage
    AddIngredientPage
        QuantityPage
    ListIngredientsPage

    Save button
```

This AddRecipe uses a mediator pattern: When u add an ingredient in AddIngredientPage the Messages.IngredientsChanged message is send. The ListIngredientsPage Listens to it and updates itself.

Each subpage receives the mediator class as a parameter. Each subpage creates it's own viewmodel.

Example:

```
public AddIngredientsPage(Recipe recipe,Mediator mediator){
    this._recipe = recipe;
    this._mediator= mediator;
    this.DataContext = new AddIngredientsViewModel(recipe, mediator);
}
```

The viewModel doesnt know about the view and each page only knows its own view model.

Now here is my problem: when the user enters invalid information in quantityPage i want an error dialog the pop up when the user clicks the save button in AddRecipePage. the dialog should give a meaningfull error mesage.

So how do I communicate the error message between the pages?

I see 2 possible solutions:

1. Add a getErrorMessage() method in the viewModel of Quantity page then put this message in each Page and viewModel in the chain until i reach AddRecipeViewModel(which then also needs to know about AddRecipePage to reach it). This would give me really messy code so i don't like this.
2. Use the mediator: the mediator is not really meant for error handling. it would then need to send messages when ever some textbox loses focus and not when the save button is clicked. It can recieve multiple error messages for diffeenrt controls that then need to be stored in AddRecipeViewModel to show them all. But when a user enters invalid input and after that gives right input in the same message, the stored erro message in AddRecipeViewModel should then be deleted. So this is also a terrible solution.

Anyone has a better idea?

thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [Event Aggregator](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html) pattern. Keep in mind that error reporting and handling is *domain-agnostic* feature of virtually every software program and as such, should not be a part of your view models but rather handled as a separate component.

Both of your proposed solutions violate [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and I'd avoid them on this very premise (they add extra responsibility of error handling to components with *already well-defined responsibilities*).

Back to event aggregator. What you need is a component (let's call it *error presenter*) which will subscribe to event aggregator's error events (raised either by your view models or views, depending on error context). Such component will then instantiate appropriate error view and show it to user:

```
// Ingridients V/VM
if (!IsValid(ingridient))
    eventAggregator.Publish(new MissingIngridientsError(ingridient.Name));

// Error presenter
eventAggreagtor.Subscribe<Error>(this.DisplayErrorPopup);

// DisplayErrorPopup
var errorViewModel = new ErrorViewModel(error);
var errorPopupView = new ErrorPopupView(errorViewModel);
errorPopupView.Show();
```

Note that in order for such setup to work, `EventAggregator` must be *application-wide* component, with single instance most likely.